# Form last location when minimized to system tray loop

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am using the application setting Location of the form to store the application last location so that when the app is opened again, it opens exactly where I left off.

I also use the NotifyIcon control to send the application to the system tray when minimized. An odd behavior is if the app is in the system tray when it is killed (ie through task manager) then the next time the app is opened, it opens to the system tray. Which is fine (although I prefer it to open normally on the screen), but when you double click on the icon in the system tray the app moves to the task bar, and if I click the icon on the taskbar it moves back to the system tray and then gets stuck in an infinite loop.

I am using the form_resize method as such:

```
Private Sub Form1_Resize(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
    If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then
        NotifyIcon1.Visible = True
        NotifyIcon1.Icon = Me.Icon
        NotifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(50000)
        ShowInTaskbar = False
    End If
End Sub
```

And then setting the doubleclick method of NotifyIcon as:

```
Private Sub NotifyIcon1_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NotifyIcon1.DoubleClick
    ShowInTaskbar = True
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
    NotifyIcon1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Everything works fine if I don't use the last location setting but that means the application opens up in random places. As soon as I add the last location setting it exhibits the behavior above.

Any ides what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How and when do you save the `.Location` property?

Comment: Don't use the`ShowInTaskbar` property. Show/Hide the Form instead.

Comment: @JQSOFT - I tried me.show() and me.hide() and it does the same thing.

Comment: @Idle_Mind - in application settings I add the name, type: System.Drawing.Point, Scope:User, Value: 0,0. Then on the form set that name under ApplicationSettngs>Location.

Comment: You need to update the code accordingly. Instead of checking the `WindowState`, check the `Visible` property.  The Form will show in the last `WindowState`, whether `Normal`, `Minimized`, `Maximized`, ....

Comment: Instead of binding it through the designer, you could manually save that value when the form closes, then set it again when the form opens.  You could also create a setting that tracks whether it should open directly from the tray.  Just make sure the form is actual visible when you save the location setting so that you don't end up saving erroneous values.

Comment: @Idle_Mind - I tried using My.Settings.Save() in the form closing method but this didn't seem to do anything. I thought that would save the location?

Comment: It does...but I would also remove it from the Application Settings for the Form and load/save it manually.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Yep, that seems to have done the trick. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
Dim IsLoaded As Boolean
    Private Sub Form1_LocationChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.LocationChanged
        If IsLoaded Then
            SaveSetting("My App", "App settings", "LocationX", Location.X.ToString)
            SaveSetting("My App", "App settings", "LocationY", Location.Y.ToString)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Location = New Point(CInt(GetSetting("My App", "App settings", "LocationX", "0")), _
                             CInt(GetSetting("My App", "App settings", "LocationY", "0")))
        IsLoaded = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: Add an explanation please